# Do I have to pay for create .IPA file

Tags: ios, ipad, ipa

I'm using Xcode for develop one simple in house app for ipad.

I know how to create .IPA file from build and archive option in xCode but for that
Do I need to pay 99$ for iOS Developer Program .?

Is there any other way since i'm doing only one APP for in house or I have to pay 99$ to apple.

I tried to Google it there is no standard Answer.

Comment: if you are not willing to pay you have to crack your device ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yep.

If you want to deploy onto actual devices, you need to have a provisioning profile (or a cert allowing you to make ad-hoc builds).

To get either, you need access to the Provisioning Portal. To get access to the portal, you need to pay $99.

Answer (score 1):

To develop in house iOS applications, you need to sign up with the enterprise developer program, which is $299/year. For more info on the enterprise program: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Alternatively, you can jailbreak, at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

**NO**

However, the only way to create an app for iPad without paying the 99$ would be to create a .app file instead of .ipa and install it on your jailbroken device.

Comment: Select Product -> Build For -> Archiving, then expand the Products folder in the navigator, right-click the app and choose Show in Finder.